# How do you make a paragraph indent within a table?

Tags: tables, indentation, paragraphs

I can manually try and indent, but it only works on the first 'paragraph' within the cell, and the \hspace won't even work with the second paragraph. Is there an easier way?

```
\ctable[
    cap= A short caption,
    caption= This is a longer caption,
    ]{lp{2in}p{2in}}{}{\FL
    title1 & title2 & title3\ML
    label &
    \hspace{1em} This is paragraph one.  This is paragraph one.\newline
    \hspace{1em} This is paragraph two.  This is paragraph two.&
    \hspace{1em} This is paragraph one.  This is paragraph one.\newline
    \hspace{1em} This is paragraph two.  This is paragraph two.\NN
    label2 &
    \hspace{1em} This is paragraph one.  This is paragraph one.\newline
    \hspace{1em} This is paragraph two.  This is paragraph two.&
    \hspace{1em} This is paragraph one.  This is paragraph one.\newline
    \hspace{1em} This is paragraph two.  This is paragraph two.\LL
    }
```

As an alternative, I might try simulating a table with minipages, but after briefly trying that, it seems like this should be e

Comment: Thanks everyone. Was not aware of \endgraf, which is a useful tip. I think ultimately, I'm going to switch to nesting a list inside these tables instead of trying to hack paragraphs into place, which makes for cleaner markup and still breaks up content within each cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `\endgraf` macro -- it works the same way as `\par`, but is also allowed in places where `\par` isn't. (Thanks to egreg for the tip.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ctable}
\newcolumntype{q}[1]{>{\setlength{\parindent}{1em}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\ctable[
    cap= A short caption,
    caption= This is a longer caption,
    ]{lq{2in}q{2in}}{}{\FL
    title1 & title2 & title3\ML
    label &
    This is paragraph one.  This is paragraph one.\endgraf
    This is paragraph two.  This is paragraph two.&
    This is paragraph one.  This is paragraph one.\endgraf
    This is paragraph two.  This is paragraph two.\NN
    label2 &
    This is paragraph one.  This is paragraph one.\endgraf
    This is paragraph two.  This is paragraph two.&
    This is paragraph one.  This is paragraph one.\endgraf
    This is paragraph two.  This is paragraph two.\LL
    }

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you use `\setlength\parindent{1em}` just before the cells contents (This is paragraph one. This is...) you can suppress all the `\hspace` commands.

Comment: Alternatively, you could set the `parindent` in the column specification: `{>{\setlength\parindent{1em}}p{2in}}`

Comment: @Gonzalo: I suspected something like that, but do not know where exactly to put `\setlength{parindent}{1em}` in my MWE.

Comment: @Alan: Thanks -- I adopted your suggestion (and defined a new column type).

Comment: @lockstep: you can place `\setlength\parindent{1em}` at the beginning of the cell or, even better, as Alan suggests, in the column specification.

Comment: If you want that the `\parindent` is the same as the usual one, you can say `\AtBeginDocument{\edef\normalparindent{\the\parindent}}` and `\setlength\parindent{\normalparindent}` in the definition of the column type `q`.

Answer (score 11):

Around line ends/beginnings, LaTeX swallows spaces. To force these spaces to stay in place, use `\hspace*{<length>}`:

```
\ctable[
  cap= A short caption,
  caption= This is a longer caption,
  ]{lp{2in}p{2in}}{}{\FL
  title1 & title2 & title3\ML
  label &
  \hspace{1em} This is paragraph one.  This is paragraph one.\newline
  \hspace*{1em} This is paragraph two.  This is paragraph two.&
  \hspace{1em} This is paragraph one.  This is paragraph one.\newline
  \hspace*{1em} This is paragraph two.  This is paragraph two.\NN
  label2 &
  \hspace{1em} This is paragraph one.  This is paragraph one.\newline
  \hspace*{1em} This is paragraph two.  This is paragraph two.&
  \hspace{1em} This is paragraph one.  This is paragraph one.\newline
  \hspace*{1em} This is paragraph two.  This is paragraph two.\LL
  }
```

[image: Setting paragraph spacing in ctable]

Another alternative stems from the fact the paragraph indentation is removed within tables since their typesetting may be somewhat different from that of regular text. Consequently, setting `\parindent` to the appropriate value within `\ctable` should do the trick:

```
...
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}This is ... \endgraf &
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}This is ... \endgraf \\
...
```

However, you have to use `\endgraf` in order to terminate paragraphs together with the `\setlength` command here since neither `\par` nor `\newline` would help.