# How to set \parindent for side heading?

Tags: tables, indentation, nicematrix

I am making tables with `NiceTabular` environment from `nicematrix` package and `S`-type columns from `siunitx` package. These tables have multi-line side headings. In accordance with guidelines for tables composition numbers must be centered vertically in cells or aligned bottom (A. Wolański, Edycja Tekstów):

[image: Adam Wolański, Edycja tekstów, PWN, p. 216]
[image: Adam Wolański, Edycja tekstów, PWN, p. 216]

It is done with the use of `m`-type column for side heading, which was suggested by @Werner [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121075/vertically-center-numbers-in-table/121077#121077).
Moreover in the case of multiline cells in side heading it is necessary to indent all lines with exception for the first line:

[image]

How to modify the code to get this effect? I tried apply the solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24551/how-do-you-make-a-paragraph-indent-within-a-table), but without success. How to force the text in the `m`-type column to be left-justified?

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}         % for NiceTabular environment
\usepackage{siunitx}            % for proper horizontal alignments of numbers
\usepackage{booktabs}       % for commands \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{
    >{\setlength{\parindent}{-1em}}m{2cm}
    S[table-format=2.2]
    S[table-format=3.1]
}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{First descr.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Second descr.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Third descr.}\\
    \midrule
    Long first side heading & 1.1 & 11.1\\
    Also long second side heading & 11.11 & 111.1\\
    \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `>{\hangindent1em}m{2cm}`

Answer (score 3):

Using @Fran comment and [the answer concerning ragged right text in the cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346237/table-and-flushleft) I got:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}      % for NiceTabular environment
\usepackage{siunitx}         % for proper horizontal alignments of numbers
\usepackage{booktabs}        % for commands \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule
\usepackage{ragged2e}        % for ragged right text

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{
    >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hangindent1em}m{3.5cm}
    S[table-format=2.2]
    S[table-format=3.1]
}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{First descr.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Second descr.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Third descr.}\\
    \midrule
    Long text in the first side heading cell & 1.1 & 11.1\\
    Also long text in the second side heading cell & 11.11 & 111.1\\
    \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]